# use type qualifiers for bean binding camel

Tags: apache-camel

Referring to article 
http://camel.apache.org/bean-binding.html

```
from("direct:myRoute1")
                .bean(new DemoRoute(), "test(Demo,Shape)")
               .end();


 from("direct:myRoute2")
                .bean(new DemoRoute(), "test(Demo,Vehicle)")
                .end();             




 interface Shape

 @Component
   class Circle implements Shape{
   }

interface Vehicle

 @Component
   class Bicycle implements Vehicle{
   }
```

I have 2 overloaded methods of test but it gives Exception

```
 Exchange[ExchangePattern: InOnly, BodyType: String, Body: org.apache.camel.component.bean.AmbiguousMethodCallException: Ambiguous method invocations
```

Comment: The types needs to use FQN names

Comment: @ClausIbsen FQN in method or in method call?

Comment: In the Camel route. Also maybe post your full source code, and stacktrace. And tell what Camel version. And also this seems like some play project with shape/vehicle, what is your real-life use-case?